# A call is in progress. you can only adjust call volume my app notification receive mi device like MI 9T , redmi 4 How to disable it

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

When i call from one sip device to another sip device more than 5 or more time. after that i receive this type notification.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXsjJ.png)

A call is in progress. notification is received How to disable it.